# Swagger UI and CXF No operations defined in spec

Tags: java, spring, cxf, swagger

I am building Spring Boot app with Apache CXF . While trying to add swagger I get No operations defined in spec! error, though I specified via annotations 1-2 opeations. 
The part of CXF config for Swagger is below:

```
factory.setFeatures(Collections.singletonList(createSwaggerFeature()));

public Swagger2Feature createSwaggerFeature() {
        Swagger2Feature swagger2Feature = new Swagger2Feature();
        swagger2Feature.setPrettyPrint(true);
        swagger2Feature.setSupportSwaggerUi(true);
        swagger2Feature.setScanAllResources(true);
        swagger2Feature.setHost("localhost:8080");
        swagger2Feature.setBasePath("/cxf/todo_list");
        swagger2Feature.setTitle("TodoList Application");
        swagger2Feature.setContact("https://www.github/abondar24");
        swagger2Feature.setDescription("Another TodoList application with Spring Boot and Swagger");
        swagger2Feature.setVersion("1.0.0");
        return swagger2Feature;
    }
```

I believe feature isn't set correctly.What am I missing?
The link for api-docs is like this: http://localhost:8080/cxf/todo_list/api-docs?url=/cxf/todo_list/swagger.json

In explore field on UI page: /cxf/todo_list/swagger.json

Comment: Can you make the code available somewhere? So far I don't see any error. You can also compare it with the working sample: https://github.com/apache/cxf/tree/master/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jax_rs/description_swagger2

Answer (score 3):

I have solved the problem. I forgot to put @Path annotation to my REST-service. After I did it swagger started working. The only thing I don't understand - how to get rid of default tag

Comment: please, could you explain a little bit the resolution? I'm facing the same problem, and I can't resolve it... Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/abondar24/TodoList/blob/master/src/main/java/org/abondar/experimental/todolist/service/RestServiceImpl.java check here the code

Comment: I was facing same problem, but issue was so silly that I had to spent hours to understand the solution, so pointing to exact line no : https://github.com/abondar24/TodoList/blob/6622b5a94a7a3f0e4f8bfb363a2656838744e003/src/main/java/org/abondar/experimental/todolist/service/RestServiceImpl.java#L30

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem,
I fixed it by Modifying controller module

[image]

Here i changed from `@Controller` => to `@RestController` and it worked.